# 2d Euler manufactured solutions

Tags: pde, fluid-dynamics, reference-request, nonlinear-equations, computational-physics

Where can I find manufactured solutions for the 2d Euler equations, with the complete analytical terms, including the Jacobian of the source term ?

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE! The point of manufactured solutions is that you can easily make your own, so it's not quite clear what you're asking for here. You can find analytical (and presumably physical) solutions to Euler's equations in http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0895717703901105

Comment: I was looking if possible for something more directly implementable, like the analytical expressions of the solutions, their analytical source terms, and the  derivatives of the source terms.

Comment: You just repeated what you wrote in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This 2004 paper by Roy et. al in *Int. J. Numer. Meth. Fluids 2004; 44:599–620* (DOI: 10.1002/d.660) should contain exactly what you're looking for:

ftp://ftp.demec.ufpr.br/CFD/bibliografia/erros_numericos/Roy_et_al_2004.pdf

You can contact the authors to obtain a copy of the FORTRAN code for the source terms (and their derivatives), or generate them yourself using symbolic manipulation software such as Mathematica.

Another paper by the same authors:

http://www.dept.aoe.vt.edu/~cjroy/Conference-Papers/aiaa2002-3110.pdf

Answer (score 3):

You can find information about Manufactured solutions in [this repository](https://github.com/manufactured-solutions). Particularly,

[Malaya, Nicholas, et al. "MASA: a library for verification using manufactured and analytical solutions." Engineering with Computers 29.4 (2013): 487-496.](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00366-012-0267-9)

That have the codes in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/manufactured-solutions/MASA).

> MASA (Manufactured Analytical Solution Abstraction) is a library written in C++ (with C, python and Fortran90 interfaces) which provides a suite of manufactured solutions for the software verification of partial differential equation solvers in multiple dimensions. Example formulations include:
>
> Heat Equation
> Laplace's Equation
> Euler Equations (with and without thermal equilibrium chemistry)
> Navier-Stokes Equations
> Reynolds Averaged Navier Stokes with Various Turbulence Models